# Error foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, reference, foreign-keys

I am trying to debug a simple SQL database. I keep getting an error that says

```
SQL query:


CREATE TABLE Groups (
  groupId            int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  leaderId           int(11) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  sportId            int(11) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  groupName          varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  membersName        varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  groupDes           TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs,
  dateCreated    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (groupId),
  FOREIGN KEY (sportId) REFERENCES Sports(sportId),
  FOREIGN KEY (leaderId) REFERENCES Users(userId)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I know that it is the FOREIGN KEY (sportId) REFERENCES Sports(sportId), line because when I remove it I get no errors and everything is fine. Something may be wrong with my sport table or just a syntax error, but I can't seem to see it. Someone please tell me I am being crazy and its a simple syntax issue. Here is the full database file I am writting.

```
DROP DATABASE if EXISTS sqlfile;
CREATE DATABASE sqlfile;
USE sqlfile;

DROP TABLE if EXISTS Users;
CREATE TABLE Users (
  userId             int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  userName           varchar (255) UNIQUE NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  password           varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  firstName          varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  lastName           varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  tel                char(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  dateCreated    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (userId)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE Groups (
  groupId            int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  leaderId           int(11) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  sportId            int(11) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  groupName          varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  membersName        varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  groupDes           TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs,
  dateCreated    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (groupId),
  FOREIGN KEY (sportId) REFERENCES Sports(sportId),
  FOREIGN KEY (leaderId) REFERENCES Users(userId)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE Members (
  memberId           int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  groupId            int(11) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  userId             int(11) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  dateCreated    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (memberId),
  FOREIGN KEY (groupId) REFERENCES Groups(groupId),
  FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES Users(userId)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE Sports (
  sportId            int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sportName          varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  dateCreated    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (sportId)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your sports table first in order to have foreign key reference in groups table

```
DROP TABLE if EXISTS Users;
CREATE TABLE Users (
....
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
CREATE TABLE Sports (
....
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
CREATE TABLE Groups (
....
  FOREIGN KEY (sportId) REFERENCES Sports(sportId),
  FOREIGN KEY (leaderId) REFERENCES Users(userId)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE Members (
....
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42e4a8)

Answer (score 0):

From examining MySQL Dump output....

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;

[your CREATEs here]

/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
```

Besides adding constraints separately, this is the only other method I know of to even create tables that reference each other in some sort of cyclic or reciprocal manner (not that your structure does).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the sports table before groups or add the constraint in the end after you have sports table there.

```
DROP DATABASE if EXISTS classbash;
CREATE DATABASE classbash;
USE classbash;

DROP TABLE if EXISTS Users;
CREATE TABLE Users (
  userId             int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  userName           varchar (255) UNIQUE NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  password           varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  firstName          varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  lastName           varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  tel                char(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  dateCreated    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (userId)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE Sports (
  sportId            int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sportName          varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  dateCreated    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (sportId)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE Groups (
  groupId            int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  leaderId           int(11) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  sportId            int(11) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  groupName          varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  membersName        varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  groupDes           TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs,
  dateCreated    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (groupId),
  FOREIGN KEY (sportId) REFERENCES Sports(sportId),
  FOREIGN KEY (leaderId) REFERENCES Users(userId)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE Members (
  memberId           int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  groupId            int(11) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  userId             int(11) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  dateCreated    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (memberId),
  FOREIGN KEY (groupId) REFERENCES Groups(groupId),
  FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES Users(userId)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```